# How to call the constructor of an inner class in a Scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, macros, inner-classes

I'm trying to use a macro to save the code used to create a function for pretty-printing. Except the function is used in the constructor of an inner class. I had this working when the class was external, but I can't figure out how to make it work for an inner class.

Here's some (simplified) example code:

```
class Outer[X](stuff: X):
  def makeInner[Y, Z](l: List[Y], f: Y => Z): Inner[Y, Z] = 
    makeInnerMacro(this, l, f).asInstanceOf[Inner[Y, Z]]

  case class Inner[Y, Z](l: List[Y], f: Y => Z, code: String)

object MyOuter extends Outer("abc"):
  val inner: Inner[Int, String] = makeInner(List(0, 1, 2), num => num.toString)
```

In an ideal world, `inner` would be `Inner(List(0, 1, 2), <func>, "num => num.toString")` and I would do a happy dance. But here's an attempt with a macro:

```
inline def makeInnerMacro[X, Y, Z](
  inline outer: Outer[X],
  inline l: List[Y],
  inline f: Y => Z,
): Outer[X]#Inner[Y, Z] = ${ makeInnerImpl('{outer}, '{l}, '{f}) }

def makeInnerImpl[X: Type, Y: Type, Z: Type](
  outer: Expr[Outer[X]],
  l: Expr[List[Y]],
  f: Expr[Y => Z],
)(using qCtx: Quotes): Expr[Outer[X]#Inner[Y, Z]] =
  import qCtx.reflect.*
  val fString: Expr[String] = Expr(f.toString)
  '{ $outer.Inner($l, $f, $fString) }
```

Unfortunately, I get an error when I try to compile:

```
scalac: Error: stale symbol; class Inner#4362 in class Outer, 
  defined in Period(1..7, run = 2), is referred to in run Period(2..2, run = 3)
dotty.tools.dotc.core.Denotations$StaleSymbol: stale symbol; 
  class Inner#4362 in class Outer, defined in Period(1..7, run = 2), is 
  referred to in run Period(2..2, run = 3)
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Similar issue: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/19351 - I'd say the issue might be that you have the same class for defining a type and and expanding a macro defined for it. In general macros works best (sometimes: at all) if you define macro AND expand it in 2 completely different compilation units. Scala 3 tries to make it less of an issue, but as you see, sometimes it fails. I guess as a workaround you can try some more generic `inline def code` which just prints `f` and then have `inline def makeInner[Y, Z](l: List[Y], f: Y => Z): Inner[Y, Z] = Inner(l, f, code(f))`

Comment: That worked for this specific example, but I had another macro that needed access to an inner class where it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: For inner classes in general (or rather for path-dependent types!) I would probably try to print AST for whatever expression I wanted to be generated and see how it looks like. Then create AST by hand. Probably using `transparent inline def` as well. But your error is about `class Foo { inline def foo = ${ macro using Foo } }` - it's a circular dependency that has to be broken, using e.g. an extension method in a different compilation unit.